# Tail probability of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here are two theorems about the "tail probability" of a random variable X

> Thm1: The expectation $E(|X|^\alpha) < \infty$ for some positive $\alpha$ 
>   if and only if 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{|X|>n^{1/\alpha}\} < \infty $$
>
> Thm2: If $E(|X|^\alpha)< \infty$ for some $\alpha$, then 
>   $$n^\alpha P\{|X|>n\} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty$$

These theorems are from the book "Introduction to probability and statistics", and the book says that Thm 2 is an immediate conseuqnece of Theorem 1, but I could not see why that is so.

If I assume the hypothesis of Thm 2, then all I can deduce using Thm 1 is that

$$ P\{|X|>n^{1/\alpha}\} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$, but how does this give me $n^\alpha P\{|X|>n\} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty$?

Comment: No, Thm 1 tells you that $ P\{|X|>n^{1/\alpha}\} $ tends to zero with $n$

Comment: @zoli Sorry that was a typo. I meant, zero :(

Comment: @zoli With the typo fixed, how do I get the conclusion of Thm2?

Comment: Thinking... : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1 shows that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}P(|X|>n^{1/\alpha})=0.$$Since those probabilities decrease as $n$ increases, this implies that $$kP(|X|>(2k)^{1/\alpha})\to0\quad(k\to\infty).$$

Now if $n$ is large, choose $k$ so that $(2k)^{1/\alpha}$is close to $n$. Then $k$ is close to $n^\alpha/2$. So $n^\alpha P(|X|>n)$ becomes as small as you want if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the Theorem 1 shows   $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}P(|X|>n^{1/\alpha})=0.$$? I don't see that clearly

Comment: @hl0202 The tail of a convergent series tends to $0$, right? That says that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty=0$. The sum I said tends to $0$ is smaller...

Comment: I now see that. The rest makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$n^{\alpha} \mathbb{P}(|X|>n) = \mathbb{E}(n^{\alpha} 1_{\{|X|>n\}}) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^{\alpha} 1_{\{|X|>n\}}).$$

Now you can either apply the dominated convergence theorem or use the fact that $$\mathbb{E}(|X|^{\alpha} 1_{\{|X|>n\}}) \leq \sum_{k \geq n^{\alpha}} \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq k^{1/\alpha})$$ and the previous theorem.